# How to automatically include all 2-way interactions in a glm model in R

Tags: r

Suppose you are using `R` and have data stored in a data frame, `M`. Then I know that

```
g <- glm(Y ~ ., data=M)
```

will automatically fit a model where `Y` is the dependent variables and all other columns of `M` are the predictors. Is there an analogously simple way to additionally include every two way interaction?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can do two-way interactions simply using `.*.` and arbitrary *n*-way interactions writing `.^n`. `formula(g)` will tell you the expanded version of the formula in each of these cases.

Answer (score 0):

See this solution
[How to include all possible two-way interaction terms in a linear model in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144532/how-to-include-all-possible-two-way-interaction-terms-in-a-linear-model-in-r)

`lm(a ~ (b + c + d)^2`

creates all possible two-way interaction.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OP's question, which is how to get all possible 2-way interactions *of all columns in the data frame when these are not known in advance*, e.g. `y ~ .^2` or `y ~ .*.` as in @MvG's existing answer ...

Comment: You are right. I misread the OP question.