# Issues with indicating interactions in R

Tags: r, interaction, p-value

```
leaps4 <- regsubsets(Y~X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7 + X1:X2 + X1:X3 + X1:X4 + X1:X5 + 
                       X1:X6 + X1:X7 + X2:X3 + X2:X4 + X2:X5 + X2:X6 + X2:X7 + 
                       X3:X4 + X3:X5 + X3:X6 + X3:X7 + X4:X5 + X4:X6 + X4:X7 + 
                       X5:X6 + X5:X7 + X6:X7, 
                     data=prostateData, nbest=1)
```

We have 97 observations and 7 variables:

```
p = rowSums(summary(leaps4)$which)
print (p)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

We want to see all the interaction between different variables but what we write that the p-value  are only indicate one interaction of the all. So how can we write the code so that the R program can indicate all the interactions. (What we write is only work for the `summary()` and the `anova()`, but not calculating the PRESSp BICp AICp and R^2p also.)

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that if you want to display more than the "best" subset, that you would increase the nbest parameter. If you want the formula to include all the one-way and two-way interactions just use "^2"

```
library(leaps)
b<-regsubsets(Y  ~  (X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7 )^2, 
                 data=prostateData, nbest=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

This formula works with lm and glm models, and I tried used it successfully with the built-in dataset `swiss` in regsubsets.

```
leaps4 <- regsubsets(Y~.*., data=prostateData, nbest=1)
```

You may also want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633403/how-to-automatically-include-all-2-way-interactions-in-a-glm-model-in-r), which describes it with glm.

[This site](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/formulae.html) also has a nice breakdown of formula calls in R.

Proof of principle:

> b<-regsubsets(Fertility~.*.,data=swiss,nbest=2)