# Math function with three variables (correlation)

Tags: algorithm, math

I want to analyse some data in order to program a pricing algorithm. 
Following dates are available:

[image]

I need a function/correlationfactor of the three variables/dimension which show the change of the Median (price) while the three dimensions (pers_capacity, amount of bedrooms, amount of bathrooms) grow. 
e.g. Y(#pers_capacity,bedroom,bathroom) = ..

note: 
- in the screenshot below are not all the data available (just a part of it) 
- median => price per night
- yellow => #bathroom

e.g. For 2 persons, 2 bedrooms and 1 bathroom is the median price 187$ per night

Do you have some ideas how I can calculate the correlation/equation (f(..)=...) in order to get a reliable factor?

Kind regards

Comment: Well a big lookup table obviously...
But predicting unknown values is going to be difficult. Looking at your example, I dont think some standard approximation will do good.
You might want to move your question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One typical approach would be formulating this as a *linear model*. Given three variables *x*, *y* and *z* which explain your observed values *v*, you assume *v* ≈ *ax* + *by* + *cz* + *d* and try to find *a*, *b*, *c* and *d* which match this as closely as possible, minimizing the squared error. This is called a [linear least squares approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#The_general_problem). You can also refer to [this Math SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/613804/35416) for one example of a specific linear least squares approximation.

If your your dataset is sufficiently large, you may consider more complicated formulas. Things like

*v* ≈
*a*<sub>1</sub>*x*<sup>2</sup> +
*a*<sub>2</sub>*y*<sup>2</sup> +
*a*<sub>3</sub>*z*<sup>2</sup> +
*a*<sub>4</sub>*xy* +
*a*<sub>5</sub>*xz* +
*a*<sub>6</sub>*yz* +
*a*<sub>7</sub>*x* +
*a*<sub>8</sub>*y* +
*a*<sub>9</sub>*z* +
*a*<sub>10</sub>

The above is non-linear in the variables but still linear in the coefficients *a*<sub>*i*</sub> so it's still a linear least squares problem.
Or you could apply transformations to your variables, e.g.

*v* ≈
*a*<sub>1</sub>*x* +
*a*<sub>2</sub>*y* +
*a*<sub>3</sub>*z* +
*a*<sub>4</sub>exp(*x*) +
*a*<sub>5</sub>exp(*y*) +
*a*<sub>6</sub>exp(*z*) +
*a*<sub>7</sub>

Looking at the residual errors (i.e. difference between predicted and observed values) in any of these may indicate terms worth adding.

Personally I'd try all this in R, since computing linear models is just [one line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11633403/1468366) in that language, and visualizing data is fairly easy as well.