# R for loop in a formula

Tags: r, loops

I need a for loop inside a formula in R. "Normal" loops are pretty straightforward in R (See for example here https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-the-first-for-loop-in-r/) However because there are " " in my formula it does not appear to work... Does anyone knows a way around this? In this formula I want ID1 to be a variable of which I have a list of 500 different IDs

```
testing <- formula(paste("STATUS ~ as.factor(data$TEMP) + C1 + ID1 * ID2 "))
```

Comment: do you want all of the two way interactions between all of the id's? if so you could modify [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633403/how-to-automatically-include-all-2-way-interactions-in-a-glm-model-in-r) with the `update()` function.

Comment: Hmm interesting! Yes I would like that! Could you help a bit (I'm not an R expert) how would that look like?

Comment: i added an answer but let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 3):

```
y <- rnorm(10)
x1 <- rnorm(10)
x2 <- rnorm(10)
x3 <- rnorm(10)
d <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)

# fit a model with all 2 way interactions
model1 <- lm(y ~ .*., d)
# remove one that you don't want
model2 <- update(model1, ~.-x2:x3)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `as.formula` rather than just `formula`. That should work on `paste`. Although your version works for me..I'm getting class `formula` both ways. Set `sep=""` so it does not include any more spaces in the formula...
Regarding the second part I'm not sure what you're asking. You want it as factor as well?