# How to include all possible two-way interaction terms in a linear model in R?

Tags: r

Is there an easy way to include all possible two-way interactions in a model in R?

Given this model:

```
lm(a~b+c+d)
```

What syntax would be used so that the model would include b, c, d, bc, bd, and cd as explanatory variables, were bc is the interaction term of main effects b and c.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633403/how-to-automatically-include-all-2-way-interactions-in-a-glm-model-in-r

Comment: Note that the duplicate question does not address how to write two-way interactions when there are columns you _don't_ want the response variable to regress on. My answer addresses that case.

Answer (score 51):

You can write the following:

```
lm(a ~ (b + c + d)^2)
```

This creates all combinations of two-way interactions between `b`, `c`, and `d`

For example:

```
lm(mpg ~ (cyl+disp+hp)^2, data = mtcars)
```

gives:

```
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ (cyl + disp + hp)^2, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          cyl         disp           hp     cyl:disp       cyl:hp      disp:hp  
  5.601e+01   -4.427e+00   -1.184e-01   -1.142e-01    1.439e-02    1.556e-02   -8.567e-05
```

Comment: Simpler: `lm(a ~ .^2)`

Comment: @tobiasegli_te Not if there are columns you _don't_ want `a` to regress on.

Comment: @tobiasegli_te comment should be an answer by itself. This is because once someone figures out 
avid_useR answer, next question is how to do it for all the variable. Its easy to remove the variable that we don't need to regress on. That's not a big issue at all

Comment: `lm(a ~ .^2)` works but is slightly dangerous in that it adds all variables other than y to the RHS. I discourage this sort of magic in my students' work. It's easy to end up with stray predictors this way. Check your model!