# How to include 3 interactions with a SINGLE predictor in lmer

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4, mixed-models, interaction

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144532/how-to-include-all-possible-two-way-interaction-terms-in-a-linear-model-in-r) that I could use `lm(a ~ (b + c + d)^2)` in order to get all possible two-way interactions in a model, but I need only the interactions with a *single* predictor. Let's say I want the possible interaction of `B + C + D` with predictor `E`.

I've tried:

```
lmer(MyVar ~ (1|ID) + (B + C + D)^E, data = data, REML = F)

Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid power in formula
```

I know that I could hard code each interaction with either `*` or `:`, but I suppose there's a simple way to do that all at once, isn't there? Thanks in advance.

Comment: like this ```(B + C + D)*E```?

Comment: @peter861222 no way, I can't believe it was that easy. Thank you very much, that was what I was looking for, indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peter already provided an answer in the comments, but just so there is a worked example here, I have used the `carrots` dataset from the `lmerTest` package to fit this kind of model.

```
#### Load Library ####
library(lmerTest)

#### Fit 3 Interactions with Predictor ####
fit <- lmer(Preference
            ~ (Work + Homesize + Age) * sens2
            + (1 + sens2 | Consumer), 
            data=carrots)
summary(fit)
```

This specific model has more than 12 parameters, so it gives a warning at the that it can't show the entire correlation matrix at the end:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [
lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: 
Preference ~ (Work + Homesize + Age) * sens2 + (1 + sens2 | Consumer)
   Data: carrots

REML criterion at convergence: 3793

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5393 -0.5531  0.0221  0.6129  3.0304 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 Consumer (Intercept) 0.194588 0.44112      
          sens2       0.002667 0.05164  0.30
 Residual             1.070431 1.03462      
Number of obs: 1233, groups:  Consumer, 103

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      4.599943   0.269675 92.130730  17.057   <2e-16 ***
Work2            0.252784   0.215224 92.355377   1.175   0.2432    
Work3            0.049107   0.202453 92.620270   0.243   0.8089    
Work4            0.350115   0.241920 92.357943   1.447   0.1512    
Work5           -0.172296   0.251901 92.336511  -0.684   0.4957    
Work6            0.142940   0.306935 92.245988   0.466   0.6425    
Work7            0.284870   0.222300 92.466369   1.281   0.2032    
Homesize3       -0.210541   0.117745 92.054098  -1.788   0.0770 .  
Age2             0.147557   0.258083 91.931134   0.572   0.5689    
Age3             0.175345   0.244237 91.940161   0.718   0.4746    
Age4             0.143185   0.286984 91.891878   0.499   0.6190    
sens2           -0.005156   0.048716 92.036870  -0.106   0.9159    
Work2:sens2     -0.026848   0.038861 92.096571  -0.691   0.4914    
Work3:sens2      0.025743   0.036536 92.167106   0.705   0.4828    
Work4:sens2      0.020395   0.043681 92.097263   0.467   0.6417    
Work5:sens2      0.041402   0.045486 92.091579   0.910   0.3651    
Work6:sens2      0.041545   0.055435 92.076468   0.749   0.4555    
Work7:sens2     -0.026257   0.040130 92.126134  -0.654   0.5145    
Homesize3:sens2  0.034216   0.021273 92.017206   1.608   0.1112    
Age2:sens2       0.050271   0.046641 91.984618   1.078   0.2839    
Age3:sens2       0.049982   0.044137 91.986480   1.132   0.2604    
Age4:sens2       0.098257   0.051868 91.973468   1.894   0.0613 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 22 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it
```

Since this may be common for models that have a lot of interaction terms, you can simply follow the advice given with the warning and just run `vcov(fit)` to see the rest:

```
22 x 22 Matrix of class "dpoMatrix"
                  (Intercept)         Work2         Work3         Work4
(Intercept)      0.0727247177 -2.460271e-02 -2.159223e-02 -2.485573e-02
Work2           -0.0246027147  4.632157e-02  2.731653e-02  2.605219e-02
Work3           -0.0215922283  2.731653e-02  4.098720e-02  2.751607e-02
Work4           -0.0248557275  2.605219e-02  2.751607e-02  5.852536e-02
Work5           -0.0188462642  2.535069e-02  2.746376e-02  2.638325e-02
Work6           -0.0590599021  2.577976e-02  2.074795e-02  2.352827e-02
Work7           -0.0196165301  2.525230e-02  2.745152e-02  2.594625e-02
Homesize3       -0.0109607544 -3.400679e-04  3.870252e-03  2.706524e-03
Age2            -0.0407749626 -6.515489e-03 -1.335698e-02 -4.201862e-03
Age3            -0.0494575617 -7.385083e-04 -7.919796e-03 -3.694373e-03
Age4            -0.0511840024 -5.047503e-04 -6.213891e-03 -8.488546e-04
sens2            0.0017103436 -5.694673e-04 -4.960309e-04 -5.737888e-04
Work2:sens2     -0.0005694673  1.082713e-03  6.301142e-04  6.007327e-04
Work3:sens2     -0.0004960308  6.301141e-04  9.510769e-04  6.326784e-04
Work4:sens2     -0.0005737887  6.007327e-04  6.326785e-04  1.367865e-03
Work5:sens2     -0.0004311883  5.838187e-04  6.310805e-04  6.061557e-04
Work6:sens2     -0.0013903112  5.995643e-04  4.776545e-04  5.446369e-04
Work7:sens2     -0.0004495020  5.815462e-04  6.308496e-04  5.958678e-04
Homesize3:sens2 -0.0002555305 -1.271474e-05  8.614862e-05  5.884019e-05
Age2:sens2      -0.0009699655 -1.494199e-04 -3.104255e-04 -9.394093e-05
Age3:sens2      -0.0011767009 -1.158708e-05 -1.805710e-04 -8.082443e-05
Age4:sens2      -0.0012155754 -8.270833e-06 -1.427594e-04 -1.592515e-05
                        Work5         Work6         Work7     Homesize3
(Intercept)     -1.884626e-02 -5.905990e-02 -1.961653e-02 -1.096075e-02
Work2            2.535069e-02  2.577976e-02  2.525230e-02 -3.400679e-04
Work3            2.746376e-02  2.074795e-02  2.745152e-02  3.870252e-03
Work4            2.638325e-02  2.352827e-02  2.594625e-02  2.706524e-03
Work5            6.345422e-02  1.792640e-02  3.446007e-02  2.839939e-03
Work6            1.792640e-02  9.420917e-02  1.785281e-02  1.291156e-03
Work7            3.446007e-02  1.785281e-02  4.941720e-02  4.034687e-03
Homesize3        2.839939e-03  1.291156e-03  4.034687e-03  1.386395e-02
Age2            -7.707013e-03  3.230279e-02 -7.764027e-03 -1.515922e-03
Age3            -1.021223e-02  4.033104e-02 -9.334598e-03  2.906882e-03
Age4            -1.878498e-02  4.116822e-02 -2.475574e-02  4.240265e-03
sens2           -4.311884e-04 -1.390312e-03 -4.495020e-04 -2.555306e-04
Work2:sens2      5.838188e-04  5.995648e-04  5.815462e-04 -1.271468e-05
Work3:sens2      6.310805e-04  4.776551e-04  6.308496e-04  8.614867e-05
Work4:sens2      6.061557e-04  5.446375e-04  5.958678e-04  5.884025e-05
Work5:sens2      1.483935e-03  4.114916e-04  7.971930e-04  6.188087e-05
Work6:sens2      4.114910e-04  2.207829e-03  4.096409e-04  2.535023e-05
Work7:sens2      7.971929e-04  4.096415e-04  1.151554e-03  9.018370e-05
Homesize3:sens2  6.188081e-05  2.535036e-05  9.018363e-05  3.267278e-04
Age2:sens2      -1.768088e-04  7.730782e-04 -1.781380e-04 -3.387819e-05
Age3:sens2      -2.350601e-04  9.623697e-04 -2.142697e-04  7.102571e-05
Age4:sens2      -4.406804e-04  9.803703e-04 -5.821051e-04  1.018839e-04
                         Age2          Age3          Age4         sens2
(Intercept)     -4.077496e-02 -4.945756e-02 -5.118400e-02  0.0017103436
Work2           -6.515489e-03 -7.385083e-04 -5.047503e-04 -0.0005694673
Work3           -1.335698e-02 -7.919796e-03 -6.213891e-03 -0.0004960309
Work4           -4.201862e-03 -3.694373e-03 -8.488546e-04 -0.0005737888
Work5           -7.707013e-03 -1.021223e-02 -1.878498e-02 -0.0004311884
Work6            3.230279e-02  4.033104e-02  4.116822e-02 -0.0013903117
Work7           -7.764027e-03 -9.334598e-03 -2.475574e-02 -0.0004495020
Homesize3       -1.515922e-03  2.906882e-03  4.240265e-03 -0.0002555306
Age2             6.660707e-02  4.917829e-02  4.874852e-02 -0.0009699654
Age3             4.917829e-02  5.965166e-02  5.751230e-02 -0.0011767008
Age4             4.874852e-02  5.751230e-02  8.235963e-02 -0.0012155754
sens2           -9.699654e-04 -1.176701e-03 -1.215575e-03  0.0023732002
Work2:sens2     -1.494201e-04 -1.158717e-05 -8.270915e-06 -0.0008009534
Work3:sens2     -3.104256e-04 -1.805711e-04 -1.427594e-04 -0.0007021649
Work4:sens2     -9.394109e-05 -8.082452e-05 -1.592525e-05 -0.0008088714
Work5:sens2     -1.768090e-04 -2.350602e-04 -4.406805e-04 -0.0006125030
Work6:sens2      7.730783e-04  9.623699e-04  9.803704e-04 -0.0019275339
Work7:sens2     -1.781381e-04 -2.142698e-04 -5.821052e-04 -0.0006376798
Homesize3:sens2 -3.387822e-05  7.102570e-05  1.018839e-04 -0.0003572095
Age2:sens2       1.574981e-03  1.162241e-03  1.152849e-03 -0.0013328873
Age3:sens2       1.162241e-03  1.410198e-03  1.360446e-03 -0.0016167476
Age4:sens2       1.152849e-03  1.360446e-03  1.949606e-03 -0.0016727270
                  Work2:sens2   Work3:sens2   Work4:sens2   Work5:sens2
(Intercept)     -5.694673e-04 -4.960308e-04 -5.737887e-04 -4.311883e-04
Work2            1.082713e-03  6.301141e-04  6.007327e-04  5.838187e-04
Work3            6.301142e-04  9.510769e-04  6.326785e-04  6.310805e-04
Work4            6.007327e-04  6.326784e-04  1.367865e-03  6.061557e-04
Work5            5.838188e-04  6.310805e-04  6.061557e-04  1.483935e-03
Work6            5.995648e-04  4.776551e-04  5.446375e-04  4.114916e-04
Work7            5.815462e-04  6.308496e-04  5.958678e-04  7.971930e-04
Homesize3       -1.271468e-05  8.614867e-05  5.884025e-05  6.188087e-05
Age2            -1.494201e-04 -3.104256e-04 -9.394109e-05 -1.768090e-04
Age3            -1.158717e-05 -1.805711e-04 -8.082452e-05 -2.350602e-04
Age4            -8.270915e-06 -1.427594e-04 -1.592525e-05 -4.406805e-04
sens2           -8.009534e-04 -7.021649e-04 -8.088714e-04 -6.125030e-04
Work2:sens2      1.510208e-03  8.888542e-04  8.476685e-04  8.246902e-04
Work3:sens2      8.888542e-04  1.334852e-03  8.949241e-04  8.931412e-04
Work4:sens2      8.476685e-04  8.949241e-04  1.908065e-03  8.579816e-04
Work5:sens2      8.246902e-04  8.931412e-04  8.579816e-04  2.068938e-03
Work6:sens2      8.398725e-04  6.749491e-04  7.659950e-04  5.829051e-04
Work7:sens2      8.214882e-04  8.927538e-04  8.437191e-04  1.121775e-03
Homesize3:sens2 -1.207554e-05  1.252882e-04  8.732358e-05  9.165766e-05
Age2:sens2      -2.118283e-04 -4.351115e-04 -1.361084e-04 -2.505820e-04
Age3:sens2      -2.290075e-05 -2.572678e-04 -1.193013e-04 -3.321938e-04
Age4:sens2      -1.572527e-05 -2.020783e-04 -2.686406e-05 -6.127763e-04
                  Work6:sens2   Work7:sens2 Homesize3:sens2
(Intercept)     -1.390311e-03 -0.0004495020   -2.555305e-04
Work2            5.995643e-04  0.0005815462   -1.271474e-05
Work3            4.776545e-04  0.0006308496    8.614862e-05
Work4            5.446369e-04  0.0005958678    5.884019e-05
Work5            4.114910e-04  0.0007971929    6.188081e-05
Work6            2.207829e-03  0.0004096415    2.535036e-05
Work7            4.096409e-04  0.0011515535    9.018363e-05
Homesize3        2.535023e-05  0.0000901837    3.267278e-04
Age2             7.730783e-04 -0.0001781381   -3.387822e-05
Age3             9.623699e-04 -0.0002142698    7.102570e-05
Age4             9.803704e-04 -0.0005821052    1.018839e-04
sens2           -1.927534e-03 -0.0006376798   -3.572095e-04
Work2:sens2      8.398725e-04  0.0008214882   -1.207554e-05
Work3:sens2      6.749491e-04  0.0008927538    1.252882e-04
Work4:sens2      7.659950e-04  0.0008437191    8.732358e-05
Work5:sens2      5.829051e-04  0.0011217754    9.165766e-05
Work6:sens2      3.072991e-03  0.0005804819    4.112908e-05
Work7:sens2      5.804819e-04  0.0016104051    1.306882e-04
Homesize3:sens2  4.112908e-05  0.0001306882    4.525614e-04
Age2:sens2       1.056816e-03 -0.0002524409   -4.911036e-05
Age3:sens2       1.318931e-03 -0.0003035236    9.540544e-05
Age4:sens2       1.345904e-03 -0.0008078267    1.388138e-04
                   Age2:sens2    Age3:sens2    Age4:sens2
(Intercept)     -9.699655e-04 -1.176701e-03 -1.215575e-03
Work2           -1.494199e-04 -1.158708e-05 -8.270833e-06
Work3           -3.104255e-04 -1.805710e-04 -1.427594e-04
Work4           -9.394093e-05 -8.082443e-05 -1.592515e-05
Work5           -1.768088e-04 -2.350601e-04 -4.406804e-04
Work6            7.730782e-04  9.623697e-04  9.803703e-04
Work7           -1.781380e-04 -2.142697e-04 -5.821051e-04
Homesize3       -3.387819e-05  7.102571e-05  1.018839e-04
Age2             1.574981e-03  1.162241e-03  1.152849e-03
Age3             1.162241e-03  1.410198e-03  1.360446e-03
Age4             1.152849e-03  1.360446e-03  1.949606e-03
sens2           -1.332887e-03 -1.616748e-03 -1.672727e-03
Work2:sens2     -2.118283e-04 -2.290075e-05 -1.572527e-05
Work3:sens2     -4.351115e-04 -2.572678e-04 -2.020783e-04
Work4:sens2     -1.361084e-04 -1.193013e-04 -2.686406e-05
Work5:sens2     -2.505820e-04 -3.321938e-04 -6.127763e-04
Work6:sens2      1.056816e-03  1.318931e-03  1.345904e-03
Work7:sens2     -2.524409e-04 -3.035236e-04 -8.078267e-04
Homesize3:sens2 -4.911036e-05  9.540544e-05  1.388138e-04
Age2:sens2       2.175354e-03  1.606007e-03  1.592130e-03
Age3:sens2       1.606007e-03  1.948116e-03  1.878419e-03
Age4:sens2       1.592130e-03  1.878419e-03  2.690248e-03
```